# Default to non Salesforce Authenticator App for MFA

Tags: authentication, identity, mfa, identity-verification

When enabling MFA for users the initial screen that prompts them is for Salesforce Authenticator with a small "Choose Another Verification Method" option near the very bottom. Our organization has another authenticator application that is approved and preferred over the Salesforce app.

We are worried that the way the MFA message is displayed by Salesforce, our users may try to use Salesforce Authenticator instead of the preferred app.

Is there a way to set it up so that the "default" is not Salesforce Authenticator?

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding,  you cannot default or make use of options to limit which authenticators can be used for MFA verification method.

Kindly review limitation [here](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000H5B7FUAV/restrict-salesforce-authenticator-app-as-the-unique-mfa-verification-method) along with [Third-Party Authenticator Apps](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mfa_supported_verification_methods_totp.htm&type=5) details.